# GaN saturation current

Tags: led, diodes

Exppresion for saturation current in GaN based diodes
$$J_{s1}=e[\sqrt\frac{D_n}{\tau_n}\frac{n_i^2}{N_D}+\sqrt\frac{D_p}{\tau_p}\frac{n_i^2}{N_A}]$$
For the simplicity, parameters:
\$e=10^{-19}, N_D=N_A=10^{16},n_i=10^{-10},D_n=25,D_p=5,\tau_n=\tau_p=10^{-9}\$
at room temperature (T = 300K) i get value ~ \$10^{-50}A/cm^2\$ (too low?), is this the right way to calculate saturation current or am i missing something ?

sorry for my bad english, and thanks in advance

Comment: is e = elementary charge * cross section of device ?

Comment: No, e just represents elementary charge, Js = Is (saturation current) * S (cross section), sorry i forgot to mention it in first sentence,... saturation current density

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe because the "... ideal saturation current is much lower than a practical device’s current at low voltages."

> The matching process of simulation to the experimental device started with the
>   dark I-V curve, which is the forward characteristic of the device when the
>   device is not stimulated by an external beta source. The dark I-V curve is
>   composed of different regions. These regions are controlled by various
>   physical parameters within the device. The space charge generation region is
>   controlled by the diffusion of charge carriers within the device. This
>   current, also called saturation current, can be calculated for an ideal diode
>   using Equation 5.
>
> $$I_{s}=qA\left(\sqrt\frac{D_n}{\tau_n}\frac{n_i^2}{N_D}+\sqrt\frac{D_p}{\tau_p}\frac{n_i^2}{N_A}\right)$$
>
> The parameters used in the equation are *q* for elementary charge; *A* for the
>   cross-sectional area of the device; *D<sub>n</sub>* and *D<sub>p</sub>* for
>   the diffusion constants in GaN of electrons and holes, respectively; and
>   *τ<sub>p</sub>* and *τ<sub>n</sub>* for the lifetime of the electrons
>   and holes in GaN, respectively; *n<sub>i</sub>* for the intrinsic carrier
>   concentration of GaN; *N<sub>D</sub>* for the donor doping concentration; and
>   *N<sub>A</sub>* for the electron doping concentration. Thus, the space charge
>   generation current is controlled by these physical parameters of the device.
>   The space charge generation current was matched by using the proper dimensions
>   and doping concentrations of the real device. However, due to the extremely
>   low value of saturation current the intrinsic carrier concentration of GaN,
>   the ideal saturation current is much lower than a practical device's current
>   at low voltages. This extra current is due to other physical parameters within
>   the device, such as trap-assisted tunneling and shunt resistance.
>
> *— [Modeling and Simulation of a Gallium Nitride (GaN) Betavoltaic Energy Converter (W.B. Ray II, M. S. Litz, J. A. Russo)](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/1011523.pdf)*

An approach for a more realistic model could be [*Thermal Study of Gallium Nitride - Metal Contact (S. S. Al-Ameer)*](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.628.342&rep=rep1&type=pdf).